# UIWebView+AFNetworking issue

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I use this code:

```
webView.loadRequest(request!, progress: nil, success: { (responce, html) in
            print("\n\n\nsuccess responce = ", html)
            return html
        }, failure: { (error) in
            print("\n\n\nerror = ", error)
        })
```

But my server has invalid SSL sertificate. So I need to set a security policy. Before I was doing it like that:

```
[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

But in AFNetworking 3 there is no `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` class anymore. How can I set security policy for all requests in AFNetworking 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFNetworking 3 equivalent of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

So you should use this, on the webView itself:

```
webView.sessionManager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

Of course the other solution is to fix the invalid certificate on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
 manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

reference : [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: This will not work because `[AFHTTPSessionManager manager]` creates a new manager which is not linked to the web view.

Comment: I have just given option instead of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` as `OP` is asking for `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is not available in `AFNetwrking 3.0`!! And OP is asking for setting security policy on all request! So he/she can use `AFHTTPSessionManager` as singleton!

Comment: `[AFHTTPSessionManager manager]` does **not** return a singleton, it creates a new session manager object.

Comment: yeah but we can create session manager object only once also which can work as singleton !